# SanDisk CruzerEdge USB stick showing 0 bytes capacity

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive

I have a 16GB stick which is recognised on my Win 10 laptop, and on an OSx iMac. I have formated it on both of them.
When I plug it into my Win 7 desktop it reports a capacity of 0 bytes and cannot be formated. I cannot access the stick from the command line (although it is given a drive letter) or change its attributes. Other USB sticks and devices work just fine (if with a curious delay before showing up in Explorer).

I have read the advice [here](https://superuser.com/questions/426218/usb-drive-unusable-and-reporting-0-bytes-capacity) but the link is long dead.

Any advice?

After the suggestion of running sg_readcap I had the following results:

> read capacity (10): transport: The device is not attatched
>
> READ CAPACITY (10) failed: Sense category: -1, try '-v' option for more information

With -v:

> read capacity(10) cdb: 25 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>
> Windows DeviceIoControl error=1167

Comment: Possible duplicate of [USB flash drive not working or is appearing as an empty disk drive, Disk Management reports "No Media" with 0 bytes size](//superuser.com/q/871850)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, because, as stated above, the drive works fine on two other machines, hence the NAND is not corrupt.

Comment: I know this is probably not the type of answer you want (hence it is a comment) but I've had the same issue - in the end, I changed the brand! I don't know why, I don't understand, and I didn't spend too much time trying to understand. I went with another well known make, and problem solved!

Comment: I wonder what's the output of `sg_readcap PDn` (where `n` is the disk number of the drive as seen in Disk Management). You can get `sg_readcap` here: http://sg.danny.cz/sg/p/sg3_utils-1.42exe.zip (32-bit) http://sg.danny.cz/sg/p/sg3_utils-1.42_mw64exe.zip (64-bit)

Comment: If I'm using readcap correctly: read capacity (10): transport: The device is not attatched

READ CAPACITY (10) failed: Sense category: -1, try '-v' option for more information

With -v: read capacity(10) cdb: 25 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Windows DeviceIoControl error=1167